# Problem with summerise with sum of multiple columns using R shiny

Tags: r, shiny, tidyverse, dt

OK, I am new to this but here goes. The problem is that in some circumstances the sum values do not appear in my datatable.
I have a dataset with several columns,  One column is named Class.  Within the Class column I have several classes.  - Senior, Junior,  etc . The data is arranged with competitors who can appear multiple times under different classes in rows. This is working. A very small section is below

```
table_dataCrewstwo <- tribble(
  ~Name1, ~Year, ~Class, ~Name, ~Time, ~Club, ~Position, ~Trophies, ~BoatType, ~DecimalTime, ~Ladies, ~Military, ~SeniorC, ~JuniorC, ~SinglesC, ~VetJuniorC, ~EndeavourC, ~KayakC, ~CanadianC, ~Folding.BoatC,
  "Fie Paul", 1984, "Senior", "Fie Paul & Te C J", "20:17:00", "Terranova Scouts & Wokingham Scouts", 8, "Scouts", "Kayak", 20.2833333333333, "Male", "Civilian", "1", "", "", "", "", "1", "", "",
  "Fie Paul", 1985, "Senior", "Fie Paul & Te C J", "19:42:48", "Wokingham Scouts", 11, "Scouts", "Kayak", 19.7133333333333, "Male", "Civilian", "1", "", "", "", "", "1", "", "",
  "Fie Paul", 1987, "Singles", "Fie Paul", "18:37:24", "Wokingham Scouts", 10, "", "Kayak", 18.6233333333333, "Male", "Civilian", "", "", "1", "", "", "1", "", "",
  "Fie Paul", 1988, "Senior", "Fie Paul & Te C J", "18:51:35", "Wokingham Scouts", 6, "Scouts", "Kayak", 18.8597222222222, "Male", "Civilian", "1", "", "", "", "", "1", "", "",
  "Fie Paul", 1990, "Senior", "Dav S M & Fie Paul", "19:27:37", "Worcester", 6, "", "Kayak", 19.4602777777778, "Male", "Civilian", "1", "", "", "", "", "1", "", ""
)
```

Fie Paul is in several classes (Senior and Singles shown) and this appears to be correct above.  However, when I do a `summerise` I get

```
Name1   First_Raced Last_Raced  SeniorT JuniorT SinglesT    VetJuniorT  EndeavourT  KayakT  CanadianT   Folding.BoatT

Fie Paul    1984    2017                        13
```

This is showing Name 1 First_Raced Last_Raced and KayakT correctly but not SeniorT SinglesT and VetJuniorT (VetJuniorT is not shown in display above).

However, competitors who are only in 1 class do appear correctly.  ie it appears that being in more than 1 class causes the `sum()` to disappear.  `case_when`??  `mutate`??  `group_by`?? `summerise`?

This is the code.

```
data <- table_dataCrewstwo %>%
  mutate(
    SeniorC = case_when(Class == "Senior"  ~ 1),
    JuniorC = case_when(Class == "Junior"  ~ 1),
    SinglesC = case_when(Class == "Singles"  ~ 1),
    VetJuniorC = case_when(Class == "Vet/Junior"  ~ 1),
    EndeavourC = case_when(Class == "Endeavour"  ~ 1),
    KayakC = case_when(BoatType == "Kayak"  ~ 1),
    CanadianC = case_when(BoatType == "Canadian"  ~ 1),
    Folding.BoatC = case_when(BoatType == "Folding Boat"  ~ 1)
  ) %>%
  group_by(Name1) %>%
  summarise(
    First_Raced = min(Year),
    Last_Raced = max(Year),
    SeniorT = sum(SeniorC),
    JuniorT = sum(JuniorC),
    SinglesT = sum(SinglesC),
    VetJuniorT = sum(VetJuniorC),
    EndeavourT = sum(EndeavourC),
    KayakT = sum(KayakC),
    CanadianT = sum(CanadianC),
    Folding.BoatT = sum(Folding.BoatC)
  )

output <- DT::renderDataTable({
  DT::datatable(
    data,
    options = list(
      search = list(
        regex = TRUE,
        caseInsensitive = FALSE,
        smart = FALSE
      ),
      pageLength = 10
    ),
    filter = list(
      position = "top",
      clear = FALSE
    ),
    rownames = FALSE
  )
})
```

If I comment out between `group_by` and `summerise` (above), it displays correctly but if the `summerise` is left running then data is missing if the competitor is in more than 1 class.  The above displays were created by commenting out the `summerise`.

Comment: Thanks for the edit.  Having looked multiple Boat Types also fail to display.  Seems any case_when followed by summerise fails to display if more than 1 case_when is present in a column.  My assumption was I created a new dataframe.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to the community!
First off, you can format your code as stated in https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help . On top of that it will always be very helpful to provide input data using the function `dput()` for example, and format (and indent) your code nicely ;-) I cannot do that yet, so I have

That being said, your problem lies in the use of `case_when(Class == "Senior"  ~ 1)`. You do not provide an alternative for when there is no hit; thus the function returns `NA` instead. This cannot be added up. Instead use `case_when(Class == "Senior"  ~ 1, TRUE ~ 0)` or, better, `ifelse(Class == "Senior", 1, 0)`, for example;

```
data <- table_dataCrewstwo %>%
  mutate(
    SeniorC = ifelse(Class == "Senior", 1, 0), # this
    JuniorC = ifelse(Class == "Junior", 1, 0),
    SinglesC = ifelse(Class == "Singles", 1, 0),
    VetJuniorC = ifelse(Class == "Vet/Junior", 1, 0),
    EndeavourC = ifelse(Class == "Endeavour", 1, 0),
    KayakC = ifelse(BoatType == "Kayak", 1, 0),
    CanadianC = ifelse(BoatType == "Canadian", 1, 0),
    Folding.BoatC = ifelse(BoatType == "Folding Boat", 1, 0)
  ) %>%
  group_by(Name1) %>%
  summarise(
    First_Raced = min(Year),
    Last_Raced = max(Year),
    SeniorT = sum(SeniorC),
    JuniorT = sum(JuniorC),
    SinglesT = sum(SinglesC),
    VetJuniorT = sum(VetJuniorC),
    EndeavourT = sum(EndeavourC),
    KayakT = sum(KayakC),
    CanadianT = sum(CanadianC),
    Folding.BoatT = sum(Folding.BoatC)
  )
```

On the other hand, you can also make sure the functions `min`, `max` and `sum` ignore the `NA` by adding the parameter `na.rm=TRUE`; thus:

```
data <- table_dataCrewstwo %>%
  mutate(
    SeniorC = case_when(Class == "Senior"  ~ 1),
    JuniorC = case_when(Class == "Junior"  ~ 1),
    SinglesC = case_when(Class == "Singles"  ~ 1),
    VetJuniorC = case_when(Class == "Vet/Junior"  ~ 1),
    EndeavourC = case_when(Class == "Endeavour"  ~ 1),
    KayakC = case_when(BoatType == "Kayak"  ~ 1),
    CanadianC = case_when(BoatType == "Canadian"  ~ 1),
    Folding.BoatC = case_when(BoatType == "Folding Boat"  ~ 1)
  ) %>%
  group_by(Name1) %>%
  summarise(
    First_Raced = min(Year),
    Last_Raced = max(Year),
    SeniorT = sum(SeniorC, na.rm = TRUE), # This
    JuniorT = sum(JuniorC, na.rm = TRUE),
    SinglesT = sum(SinglesC, na.rm = TRUE),
    VetJuniorT = sum(VetJuniorC, na.rm = TRUE),
    EndeavourT = sum(EndeavourC, na.rm = TRUE),
    KayakT = sum(KayakC, na.rm = TRUE),
    CanadianT = sum(CanadianC, na.rm = TRUE),
    Folding.BoatT = sum(Folding.BoatC, na.rm = TRUE)
  )
```

Comment: That is marveless.  It works.  Thanks, I would never have spotted that.

Comment: No worries. Just.. If it helps you, you should upvote it and/or mark it as the best answer. Thanks!